# How to Iterate Enumerable List using Razor and check whether it contains a textbox value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am passing Enumerable list of names to the View. On the View, I am displaying this list as a dropdown box. And also I have input textbox field on the view. Dropdown List is a combination of Employ number and Name, where as textbox is just an employnumber.

Now, Depending on the value of input box, I want to auto select the dropdown list with that value. My JavaScript function which tries to set the dropdown value looks like below.

```
function SetDropDownValue()
{
     var textBoxValue = $('#textbox').val();

     @foreach(var item in Model.MyList)
     {
          if (item.Contains(...))
          {
             // set the dropdown text to 'item' and return
          }
     }
}
```

In the above, I can not use the textBoxValue inside the Contains method as it's a javascript variable.

How do I check that dropdown items contains the value of the textbox value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to mix your server side (ASP.NET Razor) code with your client side code (JS) which might be complicated.

Instead, you could try the following.

1. **Implement your logic in JavaScript**
   Let your ASP.NET razor code create a Java script array where you
   store all your `Model.MyList` items. Then you can iterate through
   this list by using JavaScript. This might be easier to implement but only works if your `Model.MyList` does not change after the page was generated.
2. **Implement your logic in ASP.NET within a controller.**
   The other way would be to call a controller action with the text value as parameter. Your controller could then iterate over your model and return the appropriate result. An Ajax based approach might be most suitable here.